# Set environment variables on heroku

Tags: heroku, dotenv

I tried deploying one of my projects on heroku via my github repository. I had a .env file that had my API keys and private tokens. I want to make my repo public but it would mean revealing my .env file to everyone. I tried searching for how to set up .env for heroku but found answers that confused me even more. So is there a way to supply my env variables to herkou while I remove them from my github repository ?

Answer (score 3):

Your `.env` keys are secret and should remain so. Fear not, you can make your repo public and still keep your keys secret.

Off the back, the `.env` file is a hidden file. You should ignore this file before pushing it to version control. Add a `.gitignore` file in your top-level directory and supply all the files you want ignored from version control. You can check [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore) to see what files you may want to ignore.

If you had already committed your keys to github, meaning that there is an available copy of these keys online, i'd recommend that you generate new keys for each variable in your `.env` file. This would be the easiest way around it. With `.env` file already listed in `.gitignore`, then your next commit will omit the file and its content from version control.

#### How to load `.env` file

Assuming you have a simple structure as the one shown below where your `.env` and `config.py` files are in the top-level directory:

```py
project
 | --- .env
 | --- config.py
 | --- requirements.txt
 | --- app/
```

First, you will need to install `python-dotenv` in your virtual environment. This package helps with the loading of environment variables.

```py
(venv)$ pip3 install python-dotenv && pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
```

In  your config module, load `.env`:

```py
# config.py

import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv('.env')

class Config(object):
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
```

Your `.env` file should have this key:

```py
# .env

SECRET_KEY=<you-will-never-guess>
```

#### Set environment variables in Heroku

In your terminal, you can set the values of `.env`:

```py
(venv)$ heroku config:set SECRET_KEY=<you-will-never-guess>
```

To help interested users of your application know what keys they would need when they test the app locally, create a text file called `.env-template` and create your environment variables without passing their actual values:

```py
# .env-template

SECRET_KEY=
```